# audio stops playing after some minutes when screen is lock

Tags: html, jquery, progressive-web-apps

I've designed a PWA that the user can play some audio files.
The problem is that when the users play one of the sounds on Android and lock their screen to prevent wasting their charge, the player stops playing after approximately 5 minutes and it is funny that when they unlock the screen and click on the play button to play the rest of the audio, it starts playing from the beginning of the file!!!
Is there a way to prevent Chrome from stopping the sound when the screen is locked?

Comment: Is there a way to buffer the entire audio file then play it? (Maybe with jQuery?)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually normal behaviour for android browsers. there really isn't a workaround for this. sorry.